# How to use Oauth 2.0 Authorization in Logic App's HTTP connector?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps, httpconnection

There is an API that I need to iteratively return data from in an Azure Logic App. To do this I need two HTTP steps, 1 to receive an access token and the other to use the token to be returned the data. Unfortunately I can only receive the token through Oauth 2.0 Authorization and Azure Logic App does NOT have that authorization feature built into to the connector. Is there any way around this?